# Percentiles and sample sizes

Tags: sample-size

I have a data set of observations concerning an attribute that was collected over specific points of time.  However, there are huge variations (hundreds to tens of thousands) in the number of data points among individual time points.  The maximum and minimum values are not very different though.  I am interested in determining the attribute value at different percentiles, e.g. the 75% value.  How do huge variations in numbers effect the percentile calculation?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that there can be very large differences in quantile values depending on how many data points you have and what the spread in the min and max values are.

Consider the following example in R:

```
# Create uniform distribution with 100 points between 0 and 10,000
unif1 <- runif(100,0,10000)

# Create uniform distribution with 100,000 points between 0 and 10,000
unif2 <- runif(100000,0,10000)

# Print the quntiles for unif1
quantile(unif1)

# Print the quntiles for unif2
quantile(unif2)
```

This yields the results

```
> quantile(unif1)
   0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
222.9632 2276.7373 4078.1503 6862.3499 9962.6663 

> quantile(unif2)
   0%          25%          50%          75%         100% 
0.3043911 2507.0791144 4998.1681292 7509.9505275 9999.9719788
```

You can clearly see that unif2 is much closer to the true quintile values compared to unif1. I suggest playing a bit with the min and max values and also the number of points to see how these values change.

Comment: Great!  This makes sense to me.  Thank you very much.